# Trabalhando com dois arquivos txt

Tags: java

Tenho dois arquivos.txt diferentes entre si como exemplo: arquivo1.txt tem 1854 linhas com 6 numeros em cada linha separados por " "(um espaço). No outro arquivo2.txt eu tenho mais de 1 milhão de linhas com 6 numeros em cada linha separados por " "(um espaço tambem). Tentei fazer com que a primeira linha do arquivo2.txt analisasse todas as linhas do arquivo1.txt procurando quantos numeros iguais existem em cada linha do arquivo1.txt para daí então passar para a proxima linha do arquivo2.txt e novamente fazer a mesma analise que foi feita antes, até o final do arquivo2.txt. Mas o problema é que o meu codigo apenas está analisando a primeira linha do arquivo1.txt com a primeira linha do arquivo2.txt, depois pula para a próxima linha de ambos os arquivos. Alguem pode me ajudar a elaborar este codigo da forma como eu gostaria. O codigo é o seguinte:

```
public class Confere {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

try {
// pega os arquivos txt´s
File file = new File("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Vander/mega.txt");
File file2 = new File("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Vander/resultadomega.txt");

FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

FileReader fileReader2 = new FileReader(file2);
BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(fileReader2);

while (bufferedReader.ready()) {

bufferedReader2.ready();

String linha = bufferedReader.readLine(); // lê uma linha...
String linha2 = bufferedReader2.readLine(); // lê uma linha...

if (linha.toString().contains(linha2.toString())) { // verifica se as linhas são iguais
System.out.println("igual");
// #####################################################
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Vander/relatorio.txt", "rw");

raf.seek(raf.length());
raf.writeBytes(linha + "\r\n");
raf.close();
// ######################################################
System.out.println(linha);
} else {
System.out.println("diferente");
}
}

} catch (IOException e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

}
```

Ficaria muito grato, pois tá muito dificil...

Comment: Resumindo... Você quer contar as ocorrências de cada linha do arquivo1.txt no arquivo2.txt?

Comment: Seria isso, mostrando a linha do arquivo2.txt e quantas ocorrencias tiveram em cada linha, por exemplo: linha 1 = 4 ocorrencias e assim por diante até o fim do arquivo2.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter todas as linhas de um arquivo, use [`Files#readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
List<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/foo.txt"));
```

Para obter um array contendo os itens da string separados pelo espaço em branco, use [`\s+`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/225360/4056678) como *pattern* para o método [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
String []valores = "Stack Overflow".split("\\s+"); // ["Stack", "Overflow"]
```

Para obter os itens duplicados em dois *arrays*, **uma solução** é criar uma lista temporária e passar o *array* como argumento (em lista) para o construtor do `ArrayList`. Depois, usando o método [`retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) consegue-se os elementos que existem nas duas coleções, por exemplo:

```
String []a = {"stack", "overflow", "em", "português"};
String []b = {"stack", "overflow"};

List<String> duplicados = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a));
duplicados.retainAll(Arrays.asList(b)); // ["stack", "overflow"]
```

Com isso você consegue pegar todas as linhas do arquivos, "quebrá-las" pelo espaço em branco e verificar se os itens de uma lista existem em outra.

---

#### Exemplo

```
List<String> linhasA = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/a.txt"));
List<String> linhasB = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/b.txt"));

linhasB.forEach(linhaB -> {
   linhasA.forEach(linhaA -> {
       String []valoresLinhaB = linhaB.split("\\s+");
       String []valoresLinhaA = linhaA.split("\\s+");

       List<String> duplicados = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(valoresLinhaB));
       duplicados.retainAll(Arrays.asList(valoresLinhaA));

       if(duplicados.size() > 0){
          String mensagem = String.format("Linha B: %10s | Linha A: %10s | Duplicados: %15s",
                            linhaB, linhaA, duplicados);
          System.out.println(mensagem);
       }
   });
});
```

Exemplo de *output*:

```
Linha B:        2 4 | Linha A:  1 2 3 4 5 | Duplicados:     [2, 4]
Linha B:        2 4 | Linha A:    2 3 4 5 | Duplicados:     [2, 4]
Linha B:        2 4 | Linha A:      1 4 5 | Duplicados:        [4]
Linha B:        2 4 | Linha A:        1 4 | Duplicados:        [4]
Linha B:        2 4 | Linha A:      3 4 5 | Duplicados:        [4]
===
Linha B:      2 4 5 | Linha A:  1 2 3 4 5 | Duplicados:  [2, 4, 5]
Linha B:      2 4 5 | Linha A:    2 3 4 5 | Duplicados:  [2, 4, 5]
Linha B:      2 4 5 | Linha A:      1 4 5 | Duplicados:     [4, 5]
Linha B:      2 4 5 | Linha A:        1 4 | Duplicados:        [4]
Linha B:      2 4 5 | Linha A:      3 4 5 | Duplicados:     [4, 5]
===
Linha B:    1 2 5 4 | Linha A:  1 2 3 4 5 | Duplicados: [1, 2, 5, 4]
Linha B:    1 2 5 4 | Linha A:    2 3 4 5 | Duplicados:    [2, 5, 4]
Linha B:    1 2 5 4 | Linha A:      1 4 5 | Duplicados:    [1, 5, 4]
Linha B:    1 2 5 4 | Linha A:        1 4 | Duplicados:       [1, 4]
Linha B:    1 2 5 4 | Linha A:      3 4 5 | Duplicados:       [5, 4]
...
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda renan, é isso mesmo que eu estava tentando fazer e não consegui, com a sua ajuda posso dar continuidade agora no meu projeto. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não tive como testar,mas tenta armazenando o conteúdo dos arquivos em duas listas,exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    File file = new File("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Vander/mega.txt");
    File file2 = new File("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Vander/resultadomega.txt");

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    FileReader fileReader2 = new FileReader(file2);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(fileReader2);

    List<String> arquivo1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> arquivo2 = new ArrayList<>();

    while (bufferedReader.ready())
        arquivo1.add(bufferedReader.readLine());

    while (bufferedReader2.ready())
        arquivo2.add(bufferedReader2.readLine());

    arquivo1.stream().forEach(linhaArquivo1->{
        long qtdOcorrencia=arquivo2.stream().filter(linhaArquivo2-> linhaArquivo2.equals(linhaArquivo1)).count();
        System.out.println("Conteúdo: "+linhaArquivo1+" Quantidade Ocorrência: "+qtdOcorrencia);
    });
}
```

Comment: Tá quase lá... apliquei o codigo e ele funcionou muito bem, analisou todas as linhas, mas eu gostaria de saber como faz pra analisar o conteudo de cada linha e comparar com o conteúdo da outra linha mostrando quantos numeros iguais existem em cada linha. Tentei usar o split, o trim,  dentro do for, mas não consegui, um tokeinizador resolve o problema?

Comment: Acho que agora resolve seu problema.